# Mews\Purifier\Purifier::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem

Tags: laravel-5, htmlpurifier

I installed Mews-Purifier on laravel 5.1
I used Froala Editor.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/



<script>asdfasdfasdf</script>

<iframe>qwerqwerqwer</iframe>
```

I expect result.

```
<p><a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">https://stackoverflow.com/</a></p>

<p>qwerqwerqwer</p>
```

but, I am not see it.

when save it,

```
$data['detail'] = app('purifier')->clean($data['detail']);
```

if use Purifier::clean($data['detail']), It send error message me.

> Non-static method Mews\Purifier\Purifier::clean() should not be called statically

so, It changed.

```
$data['detail'] = (new \Mews\Purifier\Purifier)->clean($data['detail']);
```

send error message too.

> Type error: Too few arguments to function Mews\Purifier\Purifier::__construct(),

so I do changed.

```
(new Mews\Purifier\Purifier($data['detail'], ['AutoFormat.DisplayLinkURI' => true] ))->clean($data['detail');
```

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to Mews\Purifier\Purifier::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem, string given, called in

what Filesystem? what file??

Let me know How should I use it?
If I wasn't good at installing, what would it be?

Oh the installation did the following.

1. terminal

   ```
   composer require mews/purifier
   ```
2. /config/app.php

   ```
   'providers' => [
           // ...
           Mews\Purifier\PurifierServiceProvider::class,
       ],
   'aliases' => [
           // ...
           'Purifier' => Mews\Purifier\Facades\Purifier::class,
       ]
   ```
3. terminal

   ```
   php artisan vendor:publish
   ```
4. check created file. /config/purifier.php

Thanks for watching
Please let me know if you know.

Comment: mews/purifier has a build in helper at `vendor/mews/purifier/src/helpers.php`. What if you simply run `clean($data['detail']);`

Comment: Oh, problem is facade. Only ```use Purifier;``` enough it.